# Endorser client failed to connect : connection refused Error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I want to set up a Hyperledger fabric network on the Aws server, the network is working in my local system but on the AWS server I am getting below error while starting Hyperleger fabric network.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.28.0.9:7051: connect: connection refused"
peer0.org1 failed to join the channel, Retry after 3 seconds
```

version:

```
 1. Hyperledger Version: 1.4.6 
 2. Go version: go1.12.12
 3. OS/Arch:linux/amd64
 4. Chaincode:   Base Image Version: 0.4.18
```

while up the first network, by using the below command:

`./byfn.sh up -a  -s couchdb`

Please help me on how to resolve the above issues.

Comment: Are you using TLS enabled network ?

Comment: I am talking about the communication between nodes (orderers,peers etc).Is it encrypted?Because if that is the case then it could be  there are some issues with the TLS certificate.

Comment: 'CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true'  this one right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to TLS, you need to disable the TLS in `peer-base.yaml` and `docker-compose-cli.yaml` and run the network

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false

ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false
```

and also you need to change `grpcs to grpc` inside the network configuration files

and also don't use the peer and orderer TLS certificate file while deploying chaincode

Answer (score 0):

The issue what I see is , you have enabled the TLS in your network and not providing the TLS cert files in the connection profile.
If encrypting the communication between peers and orderers is not priority for you right now then you can disable it in your docker file.

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
```

or you can also enable the TLS in your network like this example and it comes mandatory if you are using RAFT ordering service.
https://github.com/IBM/raft-fabric-sample

Comment: Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed

Comment: Have you checked all your peers containers are up? and have you added this in all the peer docker file?

Comment: yes, all peer containers are running and peer-base.yaml is also there